# Where is the error in my bash script? (2)

Tags: bash, shell-script, package-management

I am trying to make a program that makes it easier to install programs in the terminal (For Crostini or if Software Center doesn't work) This is the second time askig this, I fixed my code, but  now there is more problems. Anyway, when I run it I get

```
./PackageEZ: line 37: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./PackageEZ: line 37: `done'
```

I have  no clue what is wrong, so here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

  choice="$(zenity --width=200 --height=150 --list --column "" --title="PackageEZ" \
  "Install Package" \
  "Update Package"  \
  "Search Package"  \
  "Remove Package")"

  case "${choice}" in
    "Install Package" )

     ipkg=$(zenity --entry --title="PackageEZ" --text="Type the name of the package you want to install")
     sudo apt-get install $ipkg;
     ;;

     "Update Package" )

     upkg=$(zenity --entry --title="PackageEZ" --text="Type the name of the package you want to update")
     sudo apt-get update $upkg;

     ;;

     "Search Package" )

     spkg=$(zenity --entry --title="PackageEZ" --text="Type the name of the package you want to search")
     sudo apt list $spkg;

     ;;

     "Remove Package" )

     rpkg=$(zenity --entry --title="PackageEZ" --text="Type the name of the package you want to remove")
     sudo apt-get remove $rpkg;

     ;;

done
```

The first window opens, where I can select what I want to do, but when I click on something, I get that error.

If you can help me that would be great!

Comment: You are missing several closing `)`.

Comment: You're missing the `esac` statement at the end of the case choices. There should be a semicolon at the end of each statement in the cases (i.e. - `sudo apt-get install $ipkg;`). Also, your *Search* and *Remove* choices are using the install option.

Comment: https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 0):

nvm, I just forgot to put

```
    esac
done
```